# Show that $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are differentiable functions defined on $[a,b]$ such that $F'(x)=G'(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, show that $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant. That is, show that there exists a $C\in\mathbb R$ such that $F(x)-G(x)=C$.

I'm assuming this is quite simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What can you say about $\int_a^xF'(t)\,\mathrm dt$?

Comment: If you define $H(x)=F(x)-G(x)$, what can you say about $H'(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, based on the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_a^xF'(x) = F(x) + C_1$ and $\int_a^xG'(x) = G(x) + C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants from $\mathbb R$. As $F'(x) = G'(x)$, the above expressions are equal too, hence: $F(x) + C_1 = G(x) + C_2 \Leftrightarrow F(x) - G(x) = C_2 - C_1 = C_3$, where C_3 is some constant from $\mathbb R$. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
\begin{align}
[F(x)-G(x)]-[F(a)-G(a)]
&=\int_a^x(F'(t)-G'(t))\mathrm{dt}\\
&=\int_a^x0\,\mathrm{dt}\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for all $x\in[a,b]$
$$
F(x)-G(x)=F(a)-G(a)
$$